Graph with no induced C4 or P4 has an n-1 degree vertex
Prove: Graph with no induced C4 or P4 has an n-1 degree vertex
Reuploading this question, since I haven't got a satisfied response from there.
Basically the question is: Connected Graph G with no induced C4 or P4 has an n-1 degree vertex.
I tried proving it by looking at the maximal degree vertex in G, and separating it to different cases, but everytime i get to the last case i get into a loop where i need to separate it into more cases. can i use here an induction? and if so on what? thanks in advanced.

Clearly, for all $n \leq 3$ every connected n-vertex graph has a vertex of degree $n-1$, so there is nothing to prove.
Consider a minimal counterexample $G$, that is, a graph with the smallest possible number of vertices such that $G$ has no vertex of degree $n-1$ and no induced $C_4$ or $P_4$. Suppose $G$ has a cutvertex $x$, we show that in this case there exists an induced 4-path. Since $deg_G(x) < n-1$, there exists a vertex $y \in V(G)$ such that $dist(x,y) = 2$. Denote by $H_1$ a component of $G \setminus x$ which contains $y$ and denote by $y'$ a common neighbor of $y$ and $x$ (in fact, this neighbor may not be unique). Moreover, consider a vertex $z \notin V(H_1)$ adjacent to $x$ (it exists since $x$ is a cutvertex). Then $yx,y'z,yz \notin E(G)$ and the path $yy'xz$ is an induced 4-path in $G$, a contradiction.
If $G$ has no cutvertices, then for every vertex $u \in V(G)$ the graph $G \setminus u$ is connected. Moreover, it does not have an induced $P_4$ or $C_4$ (otherwise $G$ also has it). Since $G$ is a minimal counterexample, $G \setminus u$ has a vertex $u'$ of degree $n-2$. Thus $G$ has a vertex $u'$ of degree $n-2$ nonadjacent to $u$. Since $G \setminus u'$ also has a vertex of degree $n-2$ nonadjacent to $u$, we have $deg(u) = n - 2$, hence $G$ is $(n-2)$-regular. Consider vertices $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4 \in V(G)$ such that $v_1v_3,v_2v_4 \notin E(G)$ (clearly, for all $n \geq 4$ such vertices exist). The cycle $v_1v_2v_3v_4$ is an induced 4-cycle in $G$, again a contradiction. Therefore, a minimal counterexample does not exist and we are done.

Not sure i understood it fully, they told us to look at the node with the maximal number of neighbors.

Sorry, I have no idea how to simplify the proof and why you should consider a vertex with the maximum degree.
